# clearing port for errors

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, brocade

I have an issue here, a blade has gone faulty a couple of days back. Now one of the servers (Unix) is having I/O errors. I've troubleshooted from Clariion end and everything is fine.

I need to clear the port stats for port 371(recommended by EMC), which actually is under the Index column.

In order to clear the port do I have to run the portstatsclear 12/35 (slot/port) which shows in the row where index 371 is and observer for 24 hours for any error?

Do I have to only look for CRC errors after clearing if error are increasing or something else?

The command I will be using is porterrshow.

And how do i know when were the errors cleared last?

Thanks!

Please guide me, I just want to make sure I am doing the right troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Brocade helpfiles, `portstatsclear` will just clear the values returned with `porterrshow` and the stats-block returned with `portshow`. The fact an error count has been cleared does not appear to be logged anywhere.

There are a variety of things to keep an eye on in the stats. CRC errors are one such. CRC count should not increase at all, but even a slow increase over the course of a day is indicative of something not quite right. Could be media errors creeping in (most likely), or possibly buggy driver code on the device-side.